# select whole record based on max column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hello am trying to get the whole record information based on a max value for example lets say that i have this table called animals

```
 id         name         price
____       ______       _______
 1         dog          250
 2         cat          100
 3         bird         50
```

the max price is 250 then I want to retrieve its record 
so I should get

```
id         name       price
____       ____       _____
 1          dog        250
```

here is the query that I wrote but I know its wrong

```
  Select * FROM animals where price = MAX(price);
```

Comment: Is your question about mysql or oracle? It shouldn't matter too much as there is a standard SQL syntax that should work on any DBMS. However, sometimes there are better ways to write a query that may be available only to a specific DBMS.

Comment: Did any of the answers provide a solution to your problem?

Comment: Order by price DESC limit 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_try this :)
SELECT * FROM animals
order by price desc
limit 1

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Select * FROM animals where price = (Select MAX(price) FROM animals);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you are using MySQL (which is unclear due to multiple conflicting tags), would be to `order` and use `limit`:

```
select *
from animals
order by price desc
limit 1;
```

If you are using oracle, you would need to use a subquery, I would also use a `with` then use `rownum` to specify the first record:

```
with animalsub as
(
   select id, name, price
   from animals
   order by price
)
select *
from animalsub
where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try these:

```
select * from [animals] where price= (select max(price) from [animals])

select top(1) * from [animals] order by price desc
```

Comment: I guess you should have written this 

select * from animals where price = (select max(price) from animals);

I just learned it from the new boston

Comment: yeah, it should be price. thnx :D